# UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated shows duplicate controller animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

My app's root view controller and I want to animate to new application states during the registration process. I have done something similar in a previous app with user swiping left and right and I could push and pop dynamic view controllers on demand with left or right animation no problem. However, in this app, using almost identical code I get a duplicated view controller. The navigation root view controller has a view controller A visible, if I instantiate a view controller B and attempt to animate to it the view controller A that was visible will be immediately replaced by a view controller B (no animation) and animate to a second view controller B:

```
UINavigationController *mainNavigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
UIViewController *nextViewController = nil;
//UIViewController *currentViewController = [mainNavigationController visibleViewController];

if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:K_APP_USERNAME] isEqualToString:@""]) {
    nextViewController = [self viewControllerForId:USERNAME_VIEW_CONTROLLER];
}

[mainNavigationController setViewControllers:@[nextViewController] animated:YES];
```

Like I said, this is how I did it in a previous app and it works, any ideas why is bugging out this time? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing this in a UIViewController that is within your UINavigationController with `self.navigationController setViewControllers`?

Answer (score 0):

### Found a bug

The code was getting called twice, thus the view controller was being pushed twice to the navigation controller.

:(